# Will the denso package work with the rc7 contoller?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

We are trying to use the Denso package to control a VP5243g robot and an RC7M contoller. We have a model of the robot, and we can even launch the Denso simulation files using that model.

When we try to connect to the controller, we get an error saying it couldn't connect to the robot over b-Cap. We have set the IP address of the host computer, as well as that of the controller. Is there something we might be missing to enable control of the RC7M controller from ros?

Update: Now the issue is that there is an error that cannot be cleared. Is there something in the denso_controller package that is hard coded for the vs060 that must be changed in order to use with the vp5243?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232979/will-the-denso-package-work-with-the-rc7-contoller?/) by [AustinWhitesell](https://answers.ros.org/users/26713/austinwhitesell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there something in the denso_controller package that is hard coded for the vs060 that must be changed in order to use with the vp5243?

I guess you're partly right; default IP address is hardcoded in `denso_controller/src/main.cpp`. But it's configurable in launch files e.g. `[denso_vs060_startup_skelton.launch](https://github.com/start-jsk/denso/blob/9029849c1f012d9547b4ae43b93c1485ffe56bff/denso_launch/launch/denso_vs060_startup_skelton.launch#L3). Try running:

```
roslaunch denso_launch denso_vs060_startup_skelton.launch controller_ip:=%IP_YOUR_CONTROLLERHOST%
```

By the way `vp5243` is not tested with the [denso pkg](http://wiki.ros.org/denso) AFAIK. If it works fine, it'd be greatly appreciated if you could report [on github](https://github.com/start-jsk/denso/issues) (assuming you're using the packages from there).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0